# Specify addTextChangedListener in XML

Tags: android

Is there any property for EditText I can specify TextChangedListener? I know it has 3 methods, so I want just specify value of property like below

```
 <EditText
     android:afterTextChanged="myAfterHandler"
```

However I am getting compilation errors. I can add on click listener in same way so I am wondering what is wrong on  text changed?

I know I can obtain view at certain time in Java code  and call add listener, but this solution looks really ugly.

Comment: I think this is a good question, and I don't see a usable, self-contained answer to it yet.  @yincrash hints look like a good start though.

Answer (score 9):

Android's [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#attribute_setters) now supports generating xml attributes for setters that exist in the view's class.

If you have data binding enabled, all you need to do is use the `app` namespace (don't forget to declare the namespace), so something like `app:addTextChangedListener="@{someobject.textwatcherfield}"`

Comment: why iam get error databinding use app:addTextChangeListener ?? ant error to if use ontextchange

Answer (score 0):

For use of the TextWatcher..

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property of TextChangedListener that you can specify in xml file.

You have to add textchangedListener to your edittext in Java class as described in another answer to this post.

You can just give onclick property to your views in xml file.

You can ask if you have any further queries :)

Comment: I specified in my question I do not want a solution as in the previous answer. Unfortunately nobody bothers to read a question to the end, why is everybody in a such hurry?

Comment: That is what I told you..you cannot add textchanged listener in xml file

Comment: It is perhaps the site problems not accepting short answers like "No". Certainly it is Android design flaw. I also discovered a problem if I add the listener programmatic it gets also called for programmatic text updates. Let me search if there any remedy known.